# Does sum line length measures geodetic or planar distance?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, distance, vector-grid

In QGIS i created a grid (via "create grid"), which i later split into layers of horizontal and vertical lines. Afterwards i calculated the respective cumulative line length for polygons using "Sume line length". The results i achieved differ especially for horizontal lines quite strongly (~ 25% less) from expected values (in the case where i could compare, based on another publication (values for China)).

One suggestion was, that the difference may be due to measuring planar vs. geodetic distance. Does anyone know how QGIS measures distance with this tool? May the result be subject to the projection I use?

Comment: I think when using any kind of distance/areal calculations, the CRS plays a very significant role. My guess is that the differing results you obtained could be due to whichever CRS you used.

Comment: what CRS are you using on the grid layer, and where are you getting the figures which you're comparing it with?

Comment: Mollweide and World Mercator, projected as otherwise sum line length wouldn´t work. From this paper: http://www.pnas.org/content/109/26/10263.full   The way i made the grid varies, but this should actually not explain the quite high differences. I just made a 25 Km grid. While vertical is only slightly higher ~10%, horizontal is ~25% lower, hence the ratio almost one, so I assume theirs a hidden problem which i cant find.   What is further interesting choosing Mollweide or Mercator in my approach had only a very marginal effect.

Comment: @PhilippDahlem, see [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66416/whats-the-unit-of-measurements-produced-by-sum-line-lengths) by @Underdark. `Sum line length` uses layer CRS.

Comment: check this comment.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123036/how-to-set-the-measure-tool-ellipsoid-default-behavior